# Add radio_button to each image rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, radio-button

When iterating through a collection of records, how can i add a radio_button to each image. here is what i have so far

```
<% @default_images.each do |d| %>  
 <%= image_tag(d.image_url(:campaign_form), 'data-image-id' => d.id)) %>
<% end %>
```

Im not sure on the syntax to generate a radio button with an associated image here.

I have previously done it within a form_for

```
f.collection_radio_buttons(:default_image_id, DefaultImage.all, :id, :image) do |b|
  b.label { b.radio_button + image_tag(b.object.image) }
end
```

but ive already got the collection stored within @default_images in this scenario

any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: would you like to associate images with radio button?

Comment: Do you want to show a list of radio buttons with the image replacing the text of the radio ?

Comment: yes, a radio button with its associated image next to it, no text

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing this which seems to work

```
<% @default_images.each do |d| %>
   <%= radio_button_tag :default_images, d.id %>
   <%= image_tag(d.image_url(:campaign_form)) %>
<% end %>
```